# Edit to Copy StripItem not working

Tags: c#, optimization

Is this correct code to setup a dynamic <kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Copy</kbd> `mnuStripItem`?

This code is used to copy any highlighted by the user and it does output properly.

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f = Form.ActiveForm;

        // Find the control that has focus
        Control focusedControl = f.ActiveControl;

        // See if focusedControl is of a type that can select text/data
        if (focusedControl is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = focusedControl as TextBox;
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(tb.SelectedText);
        }
        else if (focusedControl is DataGridView)
        {
            DataGridView dgv = focusedControl  as DataGridView;
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dgv.GetClipboardContent());
        }
        //else if (...more?...)
        //{
        //}

    }
```

Comment: So waht is the question. Please proof read your post

Comment: this question is, more or less, on the dynamic side. Is it correct to use if statements or is their a way to avoid writing this much code. Looking for optimized code since it does output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely correct, but normally when I have to deal with a lot of check statements, I prefer to use a switch statement. It is easier to read and i think it will also be more performing in this case (no need to use "is" and "as" statements):

```
Control focusedControl = f.ActiveControl;

switch (focusedControl.GetType())
{
    case typeof(TextBox):
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)focusedControl;
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(tb.SelectedText);
        break;

    // ...

    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Not such a good idea.  His first one should be `is TextBoxBase`.

Comment: ah true a switch would make more sense thanks. @HansPassant TextBoxBase is different from TextBox how?